# What is the first film in which a woman is created as a mate for the creator?

Tags: movie, history-of

The plot of [Island of Lost Souls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_Lost_Souls_(1932_film)) has as an important element in the Doctor's desire to create a real human  and even a scene in which the "artificial" woman proves herself to be human by crying. (I do not think this was in the original book.)

Was Island of Lost Souls the first piece of fiction to come up with the idea of creating a woman (specifically a woman) meant to be the companion of the creator? This film precedes Bride of Frankenstein who in any case was meant to be the mate for the monster, not the Dr. F.

Comment: It's a variation on Greek mythology Pygmalion and Galatea
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(mythology)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galatea_(mythology) Pygmalion falls in love with a statue he created and prays to Venus to make it a real woman. Of course I expect their may be a first science fiction variant out there.

Comment: it is worth mentioning *The Bride of Frankenstein* (1935). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bride_of_Frankenstein

Comment: @jwodder The title said film.  The body of the question said "first piece of fiction" so my answer was correct.

Comment: Do you think my answer is satisfactory?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Pygmalion et Galathée  (1898)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_and_Galatea_(1898_film)

This is a French short film directed by [Georges Méliès](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_M%C3%A9li%C3%A8s) (also responsible for *A Trip to the Moon*, thought to be the first science fiction film) that uses some ideas from the [myth of Pygmalion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(mythology)).

In the original myth, the sculptor Pygmalion creates a statue so beautiful that he falls in love with it. After Pygmalion prays to Aphrodite, the goddess grants his wish and makes the statue a real woman,  Galatea.

The point of this film was not to retell the myth. For example, Aphrodite plays no part here; the statue just comes to life spontaneously.  Instead, the film showcased some cinematic trickery so Méliès could show how clever he was. It's certainly an early instance of movie special effects.

I suspect that Méliès expected the audience to already know the myth.  Nevertheless, in the short, Pygmalion finishes the statue, he falls in love with it, and the statue comes alive.